# Vitest with React Testing Library 'Unexpected Token'

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vite, jsdom, vitest

I'm using react with ViteJS and Vitest for testing. I have set up the config for vitest and the test setup file too as you can see in the screenshots below.

`vite.config.js`

[image: vite config]

`src/test/setup.ts`

[image]

`src/app/App.tsx`

[image]

`src/app/App.spec.js`

[image]

here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

I found a lot of sources on similar issues about the topic but nothing I tried worked. I also followed the documentation for the vite config and a lot of articles too. Everyone is saying the same thing but I'm still getting this error for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used the same config with jest and it worked fine. But in this situation, I got stuck and then tried to rename the filename to `.tsx` or `.jsx` instead of `.ts` or `.js`. After that, I re-ran the test file and everything started working.

Answer (score 14):

This might be obvious to most people but in my case the issue was that the test file also has to end in ".jsx" when trying to test a ".jsx" file.

`App.test.jsx` worked for `App.jsx`

Comment: I was facing the same issue. And this worked for me :) Thanks Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `@testing-library` to `vite.config.js` alias object.